# How to read a closure content in groovy

Tags: grails, closures

I have

```
class A  {  
   String name
   String email

   static constraints = {
       email lowcase:true, anotherConfig : "value"
   }
}
```

how can I "read" the "contraints"? I'd like to get the value for lowcase, anotherConfig...

Actually, I wanna add on the fly "settings" for attributes of the class

Comment: You should use http://www.grails.org/plugin/constraints

Comment: Actually, I'd like to use it outsite graisl, I dont use grails, I just want use this feature in groovy script

Comment: take a look at that if it helps http://bytefunnel.blogspot.in/2010/03/accessing-grails-domain-constraints-at.html

Comment: It works inside "grails", in single groovy script it does not work, I really appreciate this grails way to define constraints and I'd like to use it, but in single groovy script